# GO-GTK Cross Compilation for RaspberryPi

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, gtk

I am using GO-GTK to display images, the project is working fine on amd64 but when I try to cross compile it for arm (RaspberryPi), it gives me below error.
Please advise how to cross-compile go-gtk from amd64 to arm (Raspberrypi3).

Compiler Output given below

```
    github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from ./glib.go.h:4,
                 from src/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib/glib.go:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:229:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^
github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-coverage.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-font.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-attributes.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango.h:25,
                 from ./pango.go.h:7,
                 from src/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango/pango.go:5:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:229:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
```

**ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**

```
    GOARCH="arm"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/minhaj/GoLang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOARM=""
CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -marm -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build977266484=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: Did you install a raspberry pi-native version of GTK+ somewhere and set your `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` properly to point to it? If you don't do that, you won't be able to cross-compile GTK+ programs, and it looks like you're trying to use the system-native GTK+ there.

Comment: @andlabs , please advise how do I install GTK+ version of RaspberryPi on Ubuntu and set $PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Comment: I don't know; sorry. You'll have to consult the documentation for the distro you're running on your Raspberry Pi. Your `go env` output says you already have the compiler set up, at least — look up the docs that talked about using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`...

Answer (score 1):

After removing amd64 gtk libraries and reinstalling 32bit libraries it works fine.